# PHP - Allow users to download photos they own, or friends' photos and save them temporarily in web server

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to give users the ability to download any accessible album's photos to their account (not their computer) and let them edit those photos. My problem isn't the edit part of the process but the browse-friends'-albums-select-some-photos-and-download-them part. In other words, i need something like **Pick n' Zip** download functionality.

Any suggestions, links, snippets?

I am totally new on Facebook interaction, i have no idea where to start from.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

download on your app all the files and used one library like this https://github.com/Grandt/PHPZip for create de compress file for the user.

Comment: Thank you sir, this is very useful! But i need a way to allow users select photos from their facebook album or from friends' and THEN do the rest of the process. Which is not download by the way, but it will be useful! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Oks John , you need add the Extended Permissions for access to this data, need the  User Data Permissions in this User Data Permissions, in Friends Data Permissions you need friends_photos permissions and friends_about_me for the name of your friend etc.

After using the graph api you can access for your friend list.

{idprofile}/friends

this request response the name and id of your friend, here you can access using the idprofile of your friend you can obtain this the pictures

{idprofile-friend}/photos